# Position > Positional & Inertia > Inertial, so what about speed/velocity?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there any word to indicate a relation to/dependence on speed or velocity such as `position > positional` and `inertia > inertial`?

Comment: What's an example of a sentence you'd want to use it in?

Comment: @JohnLawler Something like positional resistance or inertial force. I need to refer to a resistance dependent on the velocity/speed.

Comment: There are lots of Google hits for scientific papers with "speed-dependent".